# Web Application project versus Web Site Project in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [website or webapplication in.ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82361/website-or-webapplication-in-asp-net)
>   [web application projects v.s. web site projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056797/web-application-projects-v-s-web-site-projects)

What are the differences?

I can right click on a solution and say

Add New Website...

or

Add New Project... > Web > ASP.NET Web Application

Is one preferred over the other in terms of best practices or extensibility/performance/etc.?

Any resource links would be great, as I can't find them.

Comment: there are several duplicates of this question, e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82361/website-or-webapplication-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you'll get a lot of answers here - but from past experience working with both, I prefer Web Site Projects for 2 reasons:

- NO designer files to mess with.  I don't know how many times I've had those get out of sync, and once they do, its a real pain to put things back into working order.
- Better PUBLISH functionality.  I prefer to fully compile my apps, and the publish wizard makes this all much simpler than the web apps do.

Those 2 reasons above are the main reason I stick with web sites over web apps.  There are probably plenty of other reasons why one or the other could be better - but between the 2 of those, web site projects let me spend much less time on making things work and more time coding.

Comment: I concur, Web Site is less hassle, unless you really need to pre-compile or something